# AngularJS Single View with Multiple Form Modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I trust you are all well. There is a bit of some logic i need help figuring out and an example to help me grab the concept pretty well.

I have a signup view as shown below.
[image]

Depending on the selected button, a signup form is displayed in a modal. Assuming the advertiser button is clicked, the form looks like the picture below

[image]

However, an influencer button click should pull up this other form with an alternate social signup or form signup in a wizard as shows below.

[image]

Either of the two forms above is a form wizard and the concluding step should result in a parse of the form entries into some database i suppose.

I wish to have all of this on a single view but selective so as to be able to display the respective choice depending on the criteria selected.

How feasible is it to achieve the above and how should my logic be structured and realized. I know somehow i will have to use panel, dialogues and some functions but cant put it all together.
Will appreciate every help that can be offered.

Thanks.

Comment: what i understand from your question to show pages inside single view just to replace the middle portion on desired button click correct me if i am wrong

Comment: if so it all comes under how you are managing your routing of your application you can use $stateProvider for that

Comment: Hi Dhiraj, thanks for responding. I want to code all three forms on the same page and render only the selected one to the view and also pick the results from the respective form to the back-end.

Comment: in that case use third party navigation $stateProvider  instead of default angular routing service ng-route because $stateProvider  provides nested routing

Comment: please check my answer and do minor changes according to your app

Comment: I think you should create a modal template with conditional snippet.

Comment: @TheMechanic Could creating a modal template with conditional snippet be achieved with angular material? and could you please direct me to a resource that can help me? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the app.js file where you are doing your routing

```
                var app = angular.module('demoapp', ['ui.router']);
                app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
                    $stateProvider
                           .state('sign_up', {
                                url: '/sign_up',
                                views: {
                                    loginContent: {
                                        templateUrl: 'app/sign_up/sign_up.html',
                                        controller: 'sign_upCtrl'
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                          .state('sign_up.firstPage', {
                                url: '/sign_up-firstPage',
                                views: {
                                    loginContent: {
                                        templateUrl: 'app/sign_up/firstPage.html',
                                        controller: 'firstPageController'
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                          .state('sign_up.secondPage', {
                                url: '/sign_up-secondPage',
                                views: {
                                    loginContent: {
                                        templateUrl: 'app/sign_up/secondPage.html',
                                        controller: 'secondPagePageController'
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                }).run(function ($state){
                    $state.go('sign_up');
                });
```

And in index.html file in body tag

```
        <div ui-view="header"></div>
         <div ui-view="loginContent"></div>
         <div ui-view="footer"></div>
```

Comment: does that mean i need to code separate html pages for each of the forms? Is it possible to have all the forms in one html page and call sections of it into view? Perhaps hide and show based on selections?

Comment: I know what I'm asking is a little confusing and thats because I am confused too not knowing what is possible to achieve and whats not. So my idea is to have one single html page with ids for each of the forms. then depending on the selection criteria that form section is selected to show. Can the ui.router make it happen?

Comment: @Selase It will not be the good practice to go with id's and based on that hide or show your forms

Comment: @Selase Angular js provides greatest advantage to render html pages nestedly in single page.Which is aleready shown in my answer

Comment: @ Dhiraj : I agree and will certainly use your recommendation. I was just wondering if it was possible to do it the way i mentioned earlier that you advised against as not being a good practice. Having noted that, i suppose i will have to create an html page for each view.

Comment: Also there is this form wizard that i want to implement because of its angular-material properties. The downside is that the text-boxes turn out totally different from the angular styling. Is there a way to fix this? what causes this and how do you go about the fix. Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/rp5qJykW2DD1A7EvaVZP?p=preview

Comment: @Selase you can ask seperate question for form wizard and so we will come to know your specific problem in more detail and we can help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118993/discussion-between-selase-and-dhiraj).